# At most half of elements in $S_n$ has a square root

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Let $S_n$ be the permutation group on $\{1,...,n\}$. Prove that at most half of the elements $g \in S_n$ have a square root, ie an element $h \in S_n$ such that $g = h^2$.

This is one of the review questions I have for the upcoming abstract-algebra exam, but I could not even know where to start. The simple tick I had was to perhaps show a homomorphism between elements $g \in S_n$ to their corresponding square root. But re-thinking about that, I do not know how would that even help me.

Comment: What homomorphism on $S_n$ is pretty important? How does it relate to being a square?

Comment: Oh, and $n > 1$ is a necessary condition, the assertion is false for $n \leqslant 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Can an odd permutation have a square root?

Comment: No, clearly not.
But, to solve the question this way I would have to prove first that the number of even permutations $=$ the number of odd permutations.

Comment: @TheNotMe: Let $\sigma$ be a fixed odd permutation. Then $\tau \mapsto \tau\sigma$ maps $S_n$ bijectively to itself ...

Comment: Alternatively: The even permutations $A_n$ are exactly the kernel of the sign homomorphism $S_n\to C_2$. Thus, the non-even permutations split into cosets of $A_n$. How many such cosets are there?

Comment: Ok, so if $\sigma$ is an odd permutation and we define $t_\sigma (s) = s \sigma$ which is a bijection, it maps odd permutations to even ones and even ones to odd ones, how does that mean what I mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: @TheNotMe: (Sigh) How _doesn't_ it? I would be interested if you can propose an example of two sets with a bijection between them and they have a different number of elements?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.Thanks alot.